# can i get the html of the url by xmlhttprequest at clientside using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to retreive the page source of the url using XMLhttpRequest in javascript.I tried it but i'm not getting any response. Following is my code and i'm getting blank response.text

```
function pagesource(url) {
    var request = makeHttpObject();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        }

    };   
}

function makeHttpObject() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    catch (error) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (error) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (error) { }
    throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}
```

Comment: So alert hits and shows nothing?

Comment: it doesn't show anything

Comment: Are you sure that `url` has the value you intend?  That `.send()` call looks fishy; try `request.send('');` instead.